# Can I start an unpublished Nintex workflow?

Tags: workflow, nintex

I am building a Nintex workflow for a SharePoint 2013 list. I am making continuous changes, and I quickly run up the number of versions. Is there a way to (a) start an unpublished workflow as I am the only one who needs to run it, or (b) to unpublish a workflow so I have version 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, whatever and then publish it as 2.0 when it is ready to show to someone else?

Answer (score 1):

Publishing makes the wf available and connected to the list / library. If not published you can't run it.
Versioning:

- Saving changes the lower version level (0.1, 0.2 …)
- Publishing changes the highest version level (1.0, 2.0...)

Develop the wf in a test system or a test list where the users don't have permissions. If it's ready for use transfer it to the prod system. So you will have a version count without any gaps.

Comment: Thanks, you confirmed what I suspected. I was hoping for a way to unpublish a workflow while still working on it, the same way I would with a JavaScript file in a Site Assets library. But SharePoint doesn't treat workflows like a regular library. Too bad.